# MultiThreading error: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading

I have a Parallel.Foreach loop

```
var options = new ParallelOptions();
options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1;
Parallel.ForEach(urlTable.AsEnumerable(),drow =>
{
    using (var WCC = new MasterCrawlerClass())
    {
        WCC.MasterCrawlBegin(drow);
    }
 }
```

This loop calls the class and loops through all my DataRows, however each of those datarows either does a DataTable fill, or does an update command to a MySQL DB.  The code I have for both of those is below.

```
private static DataTable DTTable(string mysqlQuery, string queryName)
{
    DataTable DTTableTable = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter DataDTTables = new MySqlDataAdapter(mysqlQuery, MySQLProcessing.MySQLStatic.Connection);
        DataTable DataDTTablesDT = new DataTable();
        DataDTTables.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 240000;
        DataDTTables.Fill(DataDTTablesDT);
        DTTableTable = DataDTTablesDT;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        GenericLogging("Failed MySQLquery: " + ex.Message.ToString(), "MySQLProcessor", "DTTable", "", "MysqlError", "", queryName, mysqlQuery);

    }
    return DTTableTable;
}
```

```
private static void MySQLInsertUpdate(string MySQLCommand, string mysqlcommand_name)
{
    try
    {
        MySqlCommand MySQLCommandFunc = new MySqlCommand(MySQLCommand, MySQLProcessing.MySQLStatic.Connection);
        MySQLCommandFunc.CommandTimeout = 240000;
        MySQLCommandFunc.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        GenericLogging("Failed MySQLquery: " + ex.Message.ToString(), "MySQLProcessor", "DTTable", "", "MysqlError", "", mysqlcommand_name, MySQLCommand);
    }
}
```

The thing is WCC contains 10 or so voids, each of these voids accesses the MySQL functions  at least once.  So if locking is the answer, is it possible to create 1 locking function for all voids?  If so how?  If there is another way, please let me know

Thanks!

Okay as suggested i consolidated the questions

The code has now been updated to reflect locking, please see below.

`static readonly object _object = new object();`

```
public static DataTable DTTable(string mysqlQuery, string queryName)
        {
            lock (_object)
            {
                DataTable DTTableTable = new DataTable();
                try
                {
                    using (MySqlDataAdapter DataDTTables = new MySqlDataAdapter(mysqlQuery, MySQLProcessing.MySQLStatic.Connection))
                    {
                        using (DataTable DataDTTablesDT = new DataTable())
                        {
                            DataDTTables.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 240000;
                            DataDTTables.Fill(DataDTTablesDT);
                            DTTableTable = DataDTTablesDT;
                            DataDTTables.Dispose();
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    GenericLogging("Failed MySQLquery: " + ex.Message.ToString(), "MySQLProcessor", "DTTable", "", "MysqlError", "", queryName, mysqlQuery);

                }
                return DTTableTable;
            }
        }
```

This is the only code that calls the DataReader, how can there be two open data readers if there is a lock?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the problem is in the method that returns the DataTable, not the one that returns void.  You might implement a connection pool to get around the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that ADO.NET data providers generally do not allow for more than one open data reader at a time per connection. SQL Server has the concept of [multiple active result sets (MARS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), but as far as I know MySQL does not yet support it.

You will probably need to specify a different connection other than `MySQLProcessing.MySQLStatic.Connection`. There is nothing stopping you from using more than one connection. The problem here is that connections are expensive resources so you are supposed to use them sparingly.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same connection at the same time.

Do you have several thread ? Because it seems that 2 threads use the same connection to concurrently make a call.

Comment: you are correct, but i put a lock in the void so how could this even be calling it while its locked

Comment: There is no lock in the code pasted above. But are you sure it's the only method where you use this connection ? Also, you can create several connection it's low-cost as .NET have a pool of connection and doesn't create a new connection if one is already available.

Comment: Sigh... i voted to close this one and the code with lock is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081513/c-sharp-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-connection-whi

Comment: yes shit happens :). Anyway, be sure you don't use the connection at several place. And if you want to be quiet for future usage, just create a new connection.

Comment: Fabske well you would think you could close your own question without 5 votes

Comment: @Mike: Yeah I hear you. You should be able to delete it right? That does not require any voting.

Comment: Fabske I use that one connection for each Thread, but no no other code it in use

Comment: Do i lock the connection instead of the process?

Comment: I notice my server CPU spike up to 50% could there be a lock on the server

Comment: I don't get it. All this could be avoided by simply not using the static connection.

Comment: So you need to lock(yourconnection) {}
But then **all** your code that use the connection need to do the same, otherwise it'll not lock. And I don't think it's a recommended way.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer And call a new connection per DataTable holy cow thats 10,000 connections

Comment: No it's not.  You use it and dispose it and you're done with it. `using (var conn = CreateSomeConnection()) { /* use it. */ }`.  It's one connection.

Comment: I admittedly am not familiar with MySQL's implementation of connection pooling, but this kind of thing works great in Oracle and MS SQL Server.