# C# "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MultiThreading error: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081042/multithreading-error-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-c)

I'm not sure why I'm still having the issue, here is my below code, any help is appreciated.

```
public static DataTable DTTable(string mysqlQuery, string queryName)
        {
            lock (_object)
            {
                DataTable DTTableTable = new DataTable();
                try
                {
                    using (MySqlDataAdapter DataDTTables = new MySqlDataAdapter(mysqlQuery, MySQLProcessing.MySQLStatic.Connection))
                    {
                        using (DataTable DataDTTablesDT = new DataTable())
                        {
                            DataDTTables.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 240000;
                            DataDTTables.Fill(DataDTTablesDT);
                            DTTableTable = DataDTTablesDT;
                            DataDTTables.Dispose();
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    GenericLogging("Failed MySQLquery: " + ex.Message.ToString(), "MySQLProcessor", "DTTable", "", "MysqlError", "", queryName, mysqlQuery);

                }
                return DTTableTable;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You're using a static connection. Might it also have another open reader?  Create a new connection and try it instead.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer There is no other open reader, this is the only code that calls it

Comment: It doesn't have to be *this* reader.

Comment: Where is `_object` defined and assigned?

Comment: @phoog static readonly object _object = new object(); at the begining of the class

Comment: as stated above, this post is clearly a duplicate

Comment: In your previous question which seems to be 99% identical to this, someone suggested creating another connection and using that. Why did you choose to ignore that?

Comment: @Mike: Having more than one question about the **exact** same topic is going to get confusing really fast. I would abandon this question entirely and focusing all activity on your [previously posted question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10081042/158779).

Comment: @ChrisFarmer Because i put a lock in that code that is not on that question and actually voted to close it

Comment: But judging from the title, both your questions are about the datareader and not about the lock.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer it's more about the issue, i don't understand how this section of code can be called twice while there is a lock, how can there be an open reader if it's locked

Comment: It doesn't have to be THIS block of code that's using your static connection when you get this error. Are you certain that it's THIS code?

Comment: @Mike: Update your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10081042/158779) with new or different information. This is the one that is going to get closed since it got posted later.